# END LOOP wrong expression PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm having troubles working with a function in Oracle PL/SQL.

Here is the code:

```
create or replace FUNCTION FX_A (IVI NUMBER)
RETURN ListadoStrings
AS
  datos ListadoStrings;
  dato VARCHAR2(4000);
  idx NUMBER;
BEGIN
  datos := ListadoStrings();
    BEGIN
        FOR prog IN (
          SELECT TCPR.DES
          FROM TIVI TVIS
          JOIN TICPR TCPR ON (TCPR.PRO = TVIS.PRO AND TCPR.CAT = TVIS.CAT AND TCPR.TIP = TVIS.TIP)
          WHERE TVIS.IVI = IVI
        ) LOOP
            datos.extend;
            datos( datos.count ) := prog;
        END LOOP;
    END;

    BEGIN
        FOR tarea IN (
          SELECT TTAR.DES
          FROM TIVI TVIS
          JOIN TITAR TBTAR ON TBTAR.IVI = TVIS.IVI
          JOIN TMTAR TTAR ON TTAR.ITAR = TBTAR.ITAR
          WHERE TVIS.IVI = IVI
        ) LOOP
            datos.extend;
            datos( datos.count ) := tarea;
        END LOOP;
    END;

  return datos;
END FX_A;
```

When I run this script, I get the response:

*Function FX_DATOSVISITA compiled*

*Errors: check compiler log*

And In the Compiler Log I see:

*Error(17,13): PL/SQL: Statement ignored*

*Error(17,37): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type*

*Error(30,13): PL/SQL: Statement ignored*

*Error(30,37): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type*

The lines affected are both "END LOOP;" lines.

Can you help me?
Thank you!

**EDIT 1:**

Ok, now I don't have any errors, but function returns NOTHING:

```
create or replace FUNCTION FX_A (IVI NUMBER)
RETURN ListadoStrings
AS
  datos ListadoStrings;
  dato VARCHAR2(4000);
  idx NUMBER;
BEGIN
  datos := ListadoStrings();
    BEGIN
        FOR prog IN (
          SELECT TCPR.DES as des
          FROM TIVI TVIS
          JOIN TICPR TCPR ON (TCPR.PRO = TVIS.PRO AND TCPR.CAT = TVIS.CAT AND TCPR.TIP = TVIS.TIP)
          WHERE TVIS.IVI = IVI
        ) LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(prog.des );
            datos.extend;
            datos( datos.count ) := prog.des;
        END LOOP;
    END;

    BEGIN
        FOR tarea IN (
          SELECT TTAR.DES as des
          FROM TIVI TVIS
          JOIN TITAR TBTAR ON TBTAR.IVI = TVIS.IVI
          JOIN TMTAR TTAR ON TTAR.ITAR = TBTAR.ITAR
          WHERE TVIS.IVI = IVI
        ) LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tarea.des );
            datos.extend;
            datos( datos.count ) := tarea.des;
        END LOOP;
    END;

  return datos;
END FX_A;
```

I can see the results of DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tarea.des ); in the Console, but the return of the function is only "ART_MOVIL.VISITA_DATOS("

Can you help?

Comment: Try changing you variable set to `datos( datos.count ) := prog.des;` and `datos( datos.count ) := tarea.des`. You want the column value, not the row type.

Comment: @HepC can you check the edit?

Comment: The output you posted, `"ART_MOVIL.VISITA_DATOS("`, doesn't make any sense. Assuming your tables have data the revised function ought to return a populated collection. If it doesn't there's something you're doing that you haven't posted here. Consequently there's nothing more we can do to help you. Post a reproducible test case with TYPE and TABLE definitions and sample data, then maybe we can help some more.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative implementation. Replace the loops with bulk collect into local collects then squoosh them together. Set operations FTW!

```
create or replace FUNCTION FX_A (IVI NUMBER)
RETURN ListadoStrings
AS
  datos1 ListadoStrings;
  datos2 ListadoStrings;
  datos ListadoStrings;
BEGIN
  datos := ListadoStrings();

  SELECT TCPR.DES
  bulk collect into datos1
  FROM TIVI TVIS
  JOIN TICPR TCPR ON (TCPR.PRO = TVIS.PRO AND TCPR.CAT = TVIS.CAT AND TCPR.TIP = TVIS.TIP)
  WHERE TVIS.IVI = IVI;

  SELECT TTAR.DES
  bulk collect into datos2
  FROM TIVI TVIS
  JOIN TITAR TBTAR ON TBTAR.IVI = TVIS.IVI
  JOIN TMTAR TTAR ON TTAR.ITAR = TBTAR.ITAR
  WHERE TVIS.IVI = IVI;

  datos := datos1 multiset union all datos2;  

  return datos;
END FX_A;
```